# Can an executor to a will renew insurance policies of the deceased person?

Tags: united-states, insurance, home-insurance

A mother, with a relatively high net worth, dies while owning a home. While she was alive, she had home owners insurance and a personal umbrella policy. While the estate is being settled, her son wants to continue to live in the home. He was living in the home before the mother died. The son is also the executor of the will.

Can the son renew the two insurance policies that help protect the home should somebody get hurt inside the home? Is there something else the son  should do?

The son lives in the United States.

Answer (score 8):

The executor of the will should contact the insurance agent to make sure that relevant coverage continues. The policies are used to cover the assets until they are disposed of.

Once a property is removed from the estate either to sell it, or to give to the people that inherited it, the policies can be cancelled or reduced. The new owners would then be responsible for getting insurance on those items.

In the case of the son living in the house while the estate is being settled the son should also contact their insurance agent to see what insurance they need to protect their assets.

Comment: Do you think there is going to be a problem getting the relevant insurance coverage?

Comment: why would thee be a problem, unless the son is un-insurable?

Comment: If an executor is unable to pay the premiums through liquid assets of the estate, and pays using his own liquid funds, would the executor have a priority claim for reimbursement when the estate is liquidated?

Comment: @supercat yes, the executor can reimburse (reasonable) expenses incurred by themselves (and others) before distributing the bulk of the estate.